# bash script to Remove *.pom file from multiple directories which contains *.jar and *.pom aswell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Multiple directories in the Linux system contain *.jar and *.pom files. However, some directories only contain *.pom files. That I am attempting to delete but am unable to do so

Using below script, it removes all *.pom files from all the directories which contains *.jar as well.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo find /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/2021*/repositories/ -type f \( -name "*.pom" \) -exec rm {} \;
```

I'm attempting to delete only the *.pom file from the pic directory structure shown below.
**directory structure**
[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you *only* want to delete a .pom file if the directory the .pom file is in does *not* contain a .jar file?

Comment: @ShaneBishop - yes, if a directory contain .jar and .pom then I don't want to delete them. But if a directory contain only .pom then delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running `rm` directly, run a script that checks for `jar` files and deletes the `pom` only if there is no `jar`. Here we use `-execdir` to make this a bit easier and more efficient:

```
find ... -type f -name '*.pom' -execdir bash -c \
'compgen -G \*.jar > /dev/null || rm "$@"' . {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

I would code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
find /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/2021*/repositories/ -name '*.pom' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    if [ ! -f ${file%.pom}.jar ] ; then rm $file ; fi
done
```

Explanation: `find` sends all the .pom files to a `while` loop. For each .pom file, the loop checks that the corresponding .jar file does not exist and in that case, it deletes the .pom file.